# Ruby: Exposing MySQL query ability to users via RESTful API

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, sinatra

There are similar [posts like this on the internet](http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-expose-a-MySQL-database-as-a-web-service), but they seem to be targeted towards lower level languages like Java. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) for example seems to have this kind of functionality.

Here is what I want to do:

I have a large dataset of items. I want to create a RESTful API that would enable my users to perform complex queries to retrieve data from the MySQL database on my backend.

The API needs to be able to:

1. `SELECT` a table to retrieve values from
2. Be able to use common MySQL aggregate functions such as `COUNT`, `SUM`,
   and `AVG` on the results
3. Create `WHERE` conditions

Security is not an issue as this my simply an MVP for now. On a future iteration I will take security into consideration. Are there any Ruby gems which provide a framework for constructing this kind of system?

I am open to using either Sinatra or Rails for this system.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:[rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api)

> Rails::API is a subset of a normal Rails application, created for
>   applications that don't require all functionality that a complete
>   Rails application provides. It is a bit more lightweight, and
>   consequently a bit faster than a normal Rails application. The main
>   example for its usage is in API applications only, where you usually
>   don't need the entire Rails middleware stack nor template generation.

or you can use grape gem.